# qbo3 Task Access User-defined Fields

Tags: xml, qbo3

I am generating a qbo3 UI with Excel that includes the following API call:

```
api/importform/listdeep?TargetObject=Loan&TargetObjectID={LoanID}&Output=Xml
```

In the result set, the Task `XmlData` includes some fields I wish to display. However, when I map the fields to Excel columns, no value is displayed.

How do I get `XmlData` fields to display in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

The `ListDeep` query returns a `DataReader`, which plays nicely with Excel, but does not play nicely with `Xml` fields such as `XmlData`. To resolve your situation, proxy your api call with `ExecuteFlat`:

```
api/importform/executeflat?Operation=listdeep&TargetObject=Loan&TargetObjectID={LoanID}&Output=Xml
```

This will cause the qbo3 API to "flatten" `XmlData` elements into `DataReader` columns, and you can then use them any way you see fit in Excel, as if they were a normalized column.